# How to append new sheets to existing excel file in mule 3

Tags: excel, append, mule

I want to add new sheets to existing Excel File in Mule 3. I tried with using File append attribute but it is not working for .xlsx

Comment: Please provide your code so that people can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Excel xlsx files have a complex XML representation. File append just adds raw data to the end of a file, usually just breaking the expected format. Also, note that if you are using DataWeave to generate the Excel file, it only support one table in a file, as explicitly mentioned in the documenation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-formats#canonical-model-3. No tabs are possible.

For your specific requirements you could try to implement creating the excel file using some Java library that understand the Excel format with tabs, and program a Java component that can be called from a flow. One such library is Apache POI. There might be others.